# How to code the "holy grail" of nav with custom brand logo img

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

How to create following nav/brand logo responsive behavior based on the standard bootstrap nav code, please?

**Illustration:** [Responsive nav behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcY06.png)

**Code:** http://www.bootply.com/8suUu6W5ZB#

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would suggest you refer the grid layout in bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/. If you can read through and do something, we will be able to help you out. And to give you a rough idea, basically start with a row. Then have three columns inside with variable sizes. Then nest rows inside the columns as required. And just to remind you, people are gonna downvote you if you ask questions like this. Welcome to SO

Comment: Doesn't the image tell everything? I am not very CSS, so I would have hoped for some assistance. I have tried starting with the starter templates and the default header with nav but adding the brand logo breaks everything.

Comment: Actually people here can surely assist once you show them the code, and tell us your expectations of your code and may be what is the error message you are getting(In this case, you are saying it breaks somewhere). So unless you do all of the above things I have mentioned, we cannot help you as we don't have the super powers to see your code neither we can hack into your system to check your code ;). Happy coding!

Comment: OK, I have added the navbar code which really is just the plain vanilla bootstrap sample code for navbars. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what is the wrong with code you have posted?

Comment: Image is not resizing, navigation breaks around image, Image is not vertically centered with nav.

Comment: I have added Bootply for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used bootply before, So I don't know whether tags for html, body is included by bootply automatically. But I could not see those tags in your html, but could see styles for those. Basic structure of the html with bootstrap would like this. I have included a nav bar for you. So use this as a template to work on your project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=none">
        <title>Trying out bootstrap </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A WV Gates Corporation</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure to include the files of bootstrap and jquery in the appropriate paths!